# Jquery - Ajax Popup

Tags: jquery

I have a table ex.

```
Userid     username 
  3     Carlione Raymond viewmore
  2     Rich Ronalds     viewmore
  6     Stephen          viewmore
```

When user clicks on viewmore, a popup should open of that particular userid.

Could anyone suggest me this either in jquery/ajax. I would be happy if you guys refer any links so that I could learn by your support.

PHP Code

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user');
echo '<table>
       <tr> 
         <th>Userid</th>
         <th>Username</th>
       </tr>
foreach($sql as $s)
{
  $thisuser = $s->userid;
  $username = $s->username;
  echo '<tr><td>'.$thisuser.'</td>
            <td>'.username.'</td>
            <td><a class="osx" href="#">Viewmore</a>
                  <div id="osx-modal-content">
                    echo $thisuser;
                  </div>
            </td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

osx.js

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var OSX = {
    container: null,
    init: function () {
        $("input.osx, a.osx").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 

            $("#osx-modal-content").modal({
                overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
                containerId: 'osx-container',
                closeHTML: null,
                minHeight: 80,
                opacity: 65, 
                position: ['0',],
                overlayClose: true,
                onOpen: OSX.open,
                onClose: OSX.close
            });
        });
    },
    open: function (d) {
        var self = this;
        self.container = d.container[0];
        d.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $("#osx-modal-content", self.container).show();
            var title = $("#osx-modal-title", self.container);
            title.show();
            d.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var h = $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).height()
                        + title.height()
                        + 20; // padding
                    d.container.animate(
                        {height: h}, 
                        200,
                        function () {
                            $("div.close", self.container).show();
                            $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).show();
                        }
                    );
                }, 300);
            });
        })
    },
    close: function (d) {
        var self = this; // this = SimpleModal object
        d.container.animate(
            {top:"-" + (d.container.height() + 20)},
            500,
            function () {
                self.close(); // or $.modal.close();
            }
        );
    }
};

OSX.init();

   });
```

osx.css

Comment: I dont think you need ajax if you want to show details in popup. what technology you are using for backend ???

Comment: Here is the above code updated one, but all is working fine, but popup showing common userid for the users, I need a popup information for that particular user